# First row of a DF as column names

Tags: julia

How I do a make this first row as my column names instead of x1, x2....xn?

Thanks

[image: DataFrame]

I am able to load the data with `XLSX.readtable`, but unable to convert it to `DataFrame`:

```
dir = expanduser("~/Downloads/")
using DataFrames, XLSX
f = dir * "data.xlsx"
d = XLSX.readtable(f, "dados", "A:C", first_row = 5, header = false)
df = DataFrame(d)

ArgumentError: 'Tuple{Vector{Any}, Vector{Symbol}}' iterates 'Vector{Any}' values, which doesn't satisfy the Tables.jl `AbstractRow` interface
```

This fails at the last step. The spreadsheet looks like pretty standard data. If I dump the data, I get:

```
Tuple{Vector{Any}, Vector{Symbol}}
  1: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Array{Any}((225,))
      1: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 731672
      2: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 731702
      3: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 731733
      4: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 731763
      5: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 731794
      ...
      221: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 738368
      222: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 738399
      223: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 738429
      224: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 738460
      225: Dates.Date
        instant: Dates.UTInstant{Dates.Day}
          periods: Dates.Day
            value: Int64 738490
    2: Array{Any}((225,))
      1: Float64 329.16091
      2: Float64 303.23791
      3: Float64 284.96296
      4: Float64 283.10436
      5: Float64 286.08795
      ...
      221: Missing missing
      222: Missing missing
      223: Missing missing
      224: Missing missing
      225: Missing missing
    3: Array{Any}((225,))
      1: Float64 189.49076
      2: Float64 191.64219
      3: Float64 194.163
      4: Float64 194.49731
      5: Float64 198.85504
      ...
      221: Missing missing
      222: Missing missing
      223: Missing missing
      224: Missing missing
      225: Missing missing
  2: Array{Symbol}((3,))
    1: Symbol A
    2: Symbol B
    3: Symbol C
```

The spreadsheet may be downloaded at the link I have indicated in the comment section.

Comment: could you save a 4 x 4 example of your data in the xlsx format, `dump` it as is in your question and/or upload it somewhere and give the link to it.

Comment: @PatrickT Sure Thing https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QB-5kbUgghovEWppFWd1E_JJG6QIvWum?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have read this file using `CSV.read` which by default processes column names. However having a `DataFrame` such as this it is still possible to rename columns.

However let's assume you have such data:

```
julia> df = DataFrame([["a" "b"];[3 7]], :auto)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x1   x2
     │ Any  Any
─────┼──────────
   1 │ a    b
   2 │ 3    7
```

You can use `rename!` to assign the column names:

```
julia> rename!(df, Symbol.(Vector(df[1,:])))[2:end,:]
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a    b
     │ Any  Any
─────┼──────────
   1 │ 3    7
```

Comment: The original file was a .xlsx.  I used XLSX.readdata to read it an then I got a matrix., M.  When  I try DataFrame(M) gives me an error, then I have to use DataFrame(M, : auto).  I tried others functions using XLXS but none worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is [XLSX.readtable](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/api/#XLSX.readtable), which has signature

```
readtable(filepath, sheet, [columns]; [first_row], <args omitted for brevity>)
```

You can pass `first_row` to tell it where the data begins.

Comment: I updated the post with your suggestion. Can you check it, please?